# How do i send data to my Apple Watch using two different view controllers? - Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am working on a school project involving the apple watch and I have to View controllers. One is used to play music from the phone, the other is a pedometer. I need to send the pedometer data to the watch and allow the buttons for the music player to work on the watch as well. If i do those two things as separate projects they work fine since the rootViewController is set to the only view controller in each. However having multiple viewControllers makes this line of code only work for the main ViewController:

`let viewController = appDelegate.window!.rootViewController as ViewController`

Comment: What are you attempting to do with that `viewController` variable?

Comment: I have a switch that will take the watchs command and send perform actions on the viewController based on the command that comes in. For example if the Stop button is clicked:

`case "stop" :
            viewController.stopPlay()
            replyValues["status"] = viewController.nowPlayingLabel.text
`

it will run the function and get the data for the Label. It works if the two views are on separate projects as the main viewControllers, but can't get it to work when they are on the same project. @esker